# How to pass mysql datetime to input datetime-local

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I can't pass datetime mysql value to datetime local input field

MYSQL Data: 1995-10-29 08:00:00

**Ajax:**

```
function getTransaction(id){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{id:id},
        url: 'queries/getTransactionInfo.php',
        success:function(e){
            $("#pickup_date").html((e[4]));
            $("#return_date").text(e[5]);

        }
    });
}
```

**php:**

```
$select = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * from tb_transaction where `id`=?; ');
$select->bind_param('i',$id);
if($select->execute()){
    $result=$select->get_result();
    $id=0;
    while($row=$result->fetch_array()){

        $data[]=$row['requestor'];
        $data[]=$row['requestor_email'];
        $data[]=$row['pickup_location'];
        $data[]=$row['destination_location'];
        $data[]=$row['from_date'];
        $data[]=$row['to_date'];
        $data[]=$row['purpose'];
        $data[]=$row['no_passenger'];

    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}else{

}
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="datetime-local" class='form-control' id="pickup_date">
```

How can I pass it correctly? I tried using .val and .html but still not working also tried using Date.parse and still not working.

Comment: Tip: Don't put `;` in queries you're running in PHP. That's a delimiter used by interactive shells.

Comment: @tadman I already deleted those because I'm testing it first in mysql workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for `datetime-local` is like `2018-06-07T00:00` with the `T` delimiting the time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

In PHP, you can use `DateTime` class to format your time. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

**Here is an example:**

```
<?php

$time = new DateTime('1995-10-29 08:00:00');

echo $time->format('Y-m-d\TH:i')
//Output is: 1995-10-29T08:00
?>
```

**In your PHP code,**

```
....
....
$timeFormat = 'Y-m-d\TH:i';    

  while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
    $from_date = new DateTime($row['from_date']);
    $to_date = new DateTime($row['to_date']);

    $data[]=$row['requestor'];
    $data[]=$row['requestor_email'];
    $data[]=$row['pickup_location'];
    $data[]=$row['destination_location'];
    $data[]=$from_date->format($timeFormat);
    $data[]=$to_date->format($timeFormat);
    $data[]=$row['purpose'];
    $data[]=$row['no_passenger'];

}
echo json_encode($data);
....
```

It will then already be in the correct format so no need to do anything to it in Javascript.

**AJAX**

```
....
....
    success:function(e){
            $("#pickup_date").val(e[4]);
            $("#return_date").val(e[5]);

        }
```

Comment: It says jquery.min.js:2 The specified value "1995-10-29 08:00:00" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".

Comment: Can you show the value of $from_date->format($timeFormat); ?

Comment: The error you are showing still shows the "old" non-formatted value being passed to your ajax success function. This indicates to me that something is wrong in the PHP code and it's not doing the formatting. Can you verify you set the $timeFormat variable? Can you verify you executed the $from_date->format($timeFormat) and stored the return value? If you can post your new code that might be the most helpful.

Comment: Hi Alex, I formatted the datetime value using js. Should I convert it inside php?

Comment: I can retrieve all the data. The problem is I just can't pass it to date-time local

Comment: You should not format it with javascript again. That’s the point of the PHP code. If the values in e[4] and e[5] are not formatted correctly after using the code examples in my answer then something is wrong in the PHP code. Can you edit your question and add your new code?

Comment: If you’re still having trouble we can move to a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202838/discussion-between-castillo-earvin-nill-npfl-and-alex-oulapour).